# MassTransit Azure Service Bus security

Tags: masstransit

I'm using MassTransit with Azure Service Bus as a transport.  Some endpoints will live outside of our network, so I'd like to restrict the connection strings to those endpoint queues/topics while allowing the endpoints that are on our network to send to all of the other endpoints.

Is this possible?  If I try to set a connectionstring like that, errors indicating the lack of permissions to a topic that I don't think I need it to access.

Answer (score 0):

MassTransit requires *Manage* since it creates any topics/queues at startup.

If you are only sending messages to a specific queue, I have heard of some having success by ensuring the queue already exists and has the appropriate access for the credentials, but I don't know the details. In the one case I know of, they were using `queue:name` with `GetSendEndpoint` on `IBus`, and then calling `Send`.

Comment: I've had success sending from my trusted environment to the remote one, but when the remote one starts up, it can't start up without access to the entire account, even it it already has queues created.